# Issue with react webpack build while integrating with spring boot backend- server side rendering

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, webpack

We have a web application in which the backend is spring boot and front end is react. We are trying to integrate these applications in such a way that we can make use of spring boot jar file to run them both on the same port.

Following piece of java code is being used for integration.

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> htmlRouter(@Value("classpath:/static/index.html") Resource html) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(
                GET("/*"),
                request -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html)
        );
    }
```

This is working fine when we create frontend build using react-scripts build. We want to make use of webpack build as there will be multiple such applications and they will be integrated using micro front-end which will work only when webpack is in place.
When trying do so the jar file is getting built. When we run this jar file and hit the url we get following error-

```
refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8765/abc/xyz' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Part of webpack config

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    }
```

Following is the folder structure of the project

[image]